# Counting Characters UITextView issue

Tags: ios, iphone, sdk, uitextview

Having an issue displaying the number of characters in my UITextView.

Here is my code:

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {

long count = [noteView.text length];
characterCount.text = [[NSNumber numberWithInt:count] stringValue];
return NO;

}
```

Any suggestions?

Answer (score 0):

As I read it you want to have the characterCount that would be there after the change.. but you need it before the actual change.

solution is apply the change via stringByReplacingCharactersInRange and then count.

```
- (BOOL)textField:(UITextField *)textField shouldChangeCharactersInRange:(NSRange)range replacementString:(NSString *)string {
    NSString *text = [noteView.text stringByReplacingCharactersInRange:range withString:string];
    characterCount.text = @(text.length).stringValue;
    return NO;

}
```

Comment: disclaimer: code is written inline but it should be ok. the important thing is to apply the changes before getting the count!

Comment: why you always return NO is another issue IMHO ;)